# Downtime multiples servers

Tags: powershell

I need run this script for multiples servers.

somewhere can help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7j97.png)

I try:

```
$S = 'srv01','srv02'
ForEach ($Server in $S) {}
   $TotalDownTime 


But run only localhost.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Invoke-Command` to run your code on remote machines:

```
$S = 'srv01','srv02'
Invoke-Command { script } -ComputerName $S
```

Answer (score 0):

I try but, but show this message
cmdlet Where-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Property:

Comment: script: Invoke-Command -Computer $Server -ScriptBlock{ Get-EventLog  -LogName system  | 
            Where-Object ` 
            { $_.eventid -eq 6005 -OR $_.eventID -eq 6006 -AND $_.timegenerated -gt (get-date).adddays(-30) } | 
            Sort-Object -Property timegenerated |
            Foreach-Object `
            {